# How to add salesperson to print invoice ? and Which file i will edit it ? in odoo V11.0

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-11, invoice

I'm New in Odoo and need to add salesperson name who created invoicing in Invoice like from this image [salesperson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUbfI.jpg) to [invoice PDF Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6NS4.jpg) So, Which file i will edit it in Odoo files ? and How can i add salesperson Name who created invoice to Invoice print ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply inherit invoice report template and add your field value in it.